# Non-zero elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `J`. I want to identify number of non-zero elements and divide by 12 and then multiply by 100. But I get an error. I present the expected output.

```
J=[[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]]
Percent_Unvisited=(len(J[0]!=0)/12)*100
print(Percent_Unvisited)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    Percent_Unvisited=(len(J[0]!=0)/12)*100

TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

The expected output is

```
25
```

Comment: Instead of `len(J[0]!=0)` do you want `sum(i != 0 for i in J[0])`?

Comment: When `(len(J[0]!=0)` is evaluated, it returns boolean True/False, and when the len() function is applied to that boolean value, it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with `sum` to count the number of elements that are non-zero. This works because `True` and `False` are equivalent to `1` and `0`, respectively, when used in arithmetic.

```py
Percent_Unvisited = sum(x != 0 for x in J[0]) / 12 * 100
```